# TextBox.Template доступ к вложенным элементам через код

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Имеется следующий XAML код для своего компонента

```
    <TextBox Height="490" Width="490" Name="myTextBox">
            <TextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="controlLayout">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="textBoxSurface" Fill="Transparent"></Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBoxText" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Text="" 
                                   Foreground="Aqua">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
        </TextBox>
```

Если попытаться вывести в `TextBox` некое значение с помощью данного кода

```
     myTextBox.Text = "Testing string for test myTextBox";
```

то ничего не происходит. Связано это с тем, что текст отображается с помощью `TextBlock` компонента с именем `textBoxText` и уже его свойство `Text` выводит на экран сообщение.
Вопрос: как добраться до этого свойства? или же как сделать нормальный круглый `TextBlock`?

[image: пример]

Comment: Не вижу ContentPresenter, а потому интересно в чем смысл именно TextBox?

Comment: круглый TextBox для вывода результата работы. Только выводит текст(написать в нем ничего нельзя)

Comment: Ну если read-only контрол, то зачем вообще TextBox? Почему не UserControl без всяких шаблонов, где до содержимого можно добраться напрямую или через кастомные DP

Comment: потому что по другому не умею)

Comment: Ваш код визуально выдает обычный вывод текста и круг вообще не используется (и TextBox тоже) и потому непонятно, что вы вообще ожидаете увидеть. Вам лучше перефразировать вопрос в "вот пример как должен выглядеть контрол, как это сделать?"

Comment: И не забудьте особо упомянуть про Wrap. Ваш код очень похож на примеры создания круглых элементов и они действительно круглые, вот только текст в них переносится не в пределах круга, а прямоугольника TextBlock и вылазит за пределы круга. И если вам нужен Wrap внутри круга, то нужно какое то другое решение.

Comment: И нужно не добираться до вложенного TextBlock, а во вложенном TextBlock делать правильную привязку вида Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" если уж вы используете ControlTemplate

Comment: вот вы пишите, а мне понятнее не становится. скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на статью, если у Вас такая имеется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56818/discussion-between-alexandr-alexandr-and-vitidev).